# USB GSM Modem (Huawei e160) Error while connecting?

Tags: java, sms, modem, gsm

```
javax.comm.NoSuchPortException  at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier
```

[sending sms(text) from java code to mobile phone in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040665/sending-smstext-from-java-code-to-mobile-phone-in-windows)

i am using the above link source code .. but i am getting errors

```
javax.comm.NoSuchPortException
    at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:105)
    at com.codon.sms.SerialConnection.openConnection(SerialConnection.java:71)
    at com.codon.sms.Sender.send(Sender.java:45)
    at com.codon.sms.SMSClient.run(SMSClient.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codon.sms.SerialConnection.openConnection(SerialConnection.java:90)
    at com.codon.sms.Sender.send(Sender.java:45)
    at com.codon.sms.SMSClient.run(SMSClient.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the exception says it all. There is not such port it can access.

I saw the code of the link u posted. It tries to connect on COM2. Is that where the device is sitting? If it's sitting on COM1 change your code.

Another reason would be the JavaComm installation. Have you included everything? DLLs, JARs etc? If it was a DLL issue you would get the UnsatisfiedLinkError exception too but anyway.